# How to customize the calendar header text format (Material UI v5 - DatePicker)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to change the format of the string that appears at the top of the calendar in the DatePicker in Material UI v5.
Is there a way to do this?

[image]

React and Material UI are using the following versions.

- "react": "17.0.1"
- "@material-ui/core": "5.0.0-beta.0"
- "@material-ui/lab": "5.0.0-alpha.39"

I tried to set the dateFormats property of the LocalizationProvider as follows, but I could not change it.

```
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import AdapterDateFns from '@material-ui/lab/AdapterDateFns';
import LocalizationProvider from '@material-ui/lab/LocalizationProvider';
import DatePicker from '@material-ui/lab/DatePicker';

const DatePickerSample = () => {
  const [dateValue, setDateValue] = React.useState<object>(new Date(Date.now()));

  // not work.
  const formats = {
    monthAndYear: "yyyy MM",
  };

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns} dateFormats={formats}>
        <DatePicker label="DatePicker1"
            value={dateValue}
            inputFormat="yyyy/MM/dd"
            mask="____/__/__"
            onChange={(newValue) => {
                if (newValue) { setDateValue(newValue); }
            }}
            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} required />}
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

If there is a way to achieve this, I would appreciate it if you could let me know.

Comment: Is there a reason to use alfa/beta versions?

Comment: No, there is no reason to use alfa/beta versions.
I will upgrade as soon as official version is released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no normal way to do it. I've checked source code.
I guess you can use some dirty hack like this below for example. It will not working forever:

```
.PrivatePickersFadeTransitionGroup-root:first-child {
    order: 2;
}
.PrivatePickersFadeTransitionGroup-root:last-child {
    order: 1;
}
.MuiCalendarPicker-root button {
    order: 3;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I was able to change the sort order by overriding the style you described.  Thank you very much.  
However, I found that the following format changes are currently not possible.  
  [before:] August 2021, [after:] 2021 - Auggust (add a hyphen)