# Best way to change the date header title on MUI Date Picker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm looking for a way to customize the Calendar title for MUI Date Picker. The one that displays the month and year, for example, "August 2014."

[image]

I can't find any props in the API which contain what I need. But there HAS to be a way to customize this text. Essentially, I want to add a string to it.

Does anyone have any idea where I can customize this part of the date picker?

Comment: Recently covered on [github](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/4605) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68665803/how-to-customize-the-calendar-header-text-format-material-ui-v5-datepicker).. _"which contain what I need"_ -> Which format would you need?

Comment: The 2nd link is the closest thing to my problem, but they just use CSS to reverse the order of the text. I want to add new text along with the original text in the time picker.

Comment: you could write a small script where you could use `document.getElementsByClassName('PrivatePickersFadeTransitionGroup-root')` and then append a sibling or child via `var myadditionalText = 'someText'` - do you know how to do that? FYI - `insertAdjacentHTML` would work as well..

Comment: For sure that would work, but I'm looking for a strictly React approach. The above approach would be difficult because whenever a user switches the calendar view, I would have to append for each month...which I think would require internal state and would be a no op.

Comment: If you would tell me what you like to append, it would make it easier for me to answer your question/find a solution to your issue. If the string varies by month or year, just map/match them via an array with `[{name:..., value:...},{..}]`. Is this string that you want to attach used in the state or coming from the state? As you formulate your question appending a string has nothing to to with _'the react way'_..

Comment: @iLuvLogix I'd like to prepend the string `Start` and `End`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update Jan 2024:**
Take a look at the comment underneath.

**Original:**
I tried to remove the "year" and keep only months. In order to do so I searched on MUI Datepicker repository, looks like it's hard-coded as "monthAndYear" so, currently we cannot do it elegantly.

https://github.com/mui/mui-x/blob/d5ba5769bc7338f98675c954f88cf848a7ba7545/packages/x-date-pickers/src/DateCalendar/PickersCalendarHeader.tsx#L272

Comment: Date header in Mui date picker is changeable, for changing the date header, please pass dateFormats props as per your expected date format, like this. "dateFormats={{monthAndYear: 'YYYY年MM月'}}" And also for showing only month, please pass only "MM", like "dateFormats={{monthAndYear: 'MM月'}}"

For better understanding, you can also check this answer.https://stackoverflow.com/a/77286994/11559773
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Best way to change the date header title in mui date picker, you can add

```js
dateFormats={{monthAndYear: 'YYYY年MM月'}}
```

dateFormats props in your *LocalizationProvider*

```js
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';

<LocalizationProvider 
dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs} 
adapterLocale='zh-cn' 
dateFormats={{monthAndYear: 'YYYY年MM月'}}>
       <DatePicker
          value={date}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

[See the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wT4wO.png)

Comment: Thank you @Rasel Karim for your answer. It works fine for me.